How to process a message in a telegram channel in python?
I'm writing a bot that will monitor the Telegram channel and perform certain manipulations in case of a new publication there. The bot is connected to the channel and has administrator rights. In the BotFather settings, message permissions are also enabled. I tried to implement this through the channel_post_handler, but the bot does not react to new messages in the channel, although it can leave them. There are no errors in the console.
import telebot

BOT_TOKEN = 'TOKEN'

bot = telebot.TeleBot(BOT_TOKEN)

@bot.channel_post_handler(content_types=['text'])
def handle_channel_message(message):
  print('good!')

bot.polling()

what's the problem? Or point a newbie in the right direction. Thank.

As I understand it a "channel post" and a "message" are two different things on Telegram.
Try using @bot.message_handler instead

@bot.message_handler in this way, the bot listens to messages from the user in a private chat with him, and I need the bot to track the channel (not the group or chat)

Ohh okay I understand. I think I know what the problem is. "print('good!')"
Does your bot print that to the console when you post a message to the channel?

no does not print(

The docs suggest using bot.infinity_polling()

I replaced bot.polling() with bot.infinity_polling(none_stop=True) . unfortunately, it didn't work.
